# Android Animation High CPU Usage

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, cpu-usage

I'm trying to create a simple android animation. 
A bouncing google map marker.
I have already implemented a simple code for doing that, but when i run it on API 28 it's almost fine. When i run the code in every other API version, on multiple emulator and even on my phone, the CPU Usage looks extrimly high, from 35% to 80-90% during all the running time. All my main Activity looks slower.

I'm using a Constraint layout, i don't know if that can be of any helpful

That's my bounce.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:toYDelta="-50"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode= "reverse"
     />
</set>
```

That's my simple main activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        findViewById(R.id.img_pointer1_id).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bounce));
    }
}
```

Any suggestion about how to fix this / any alternative solution?

Comment: I suggest this doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute

Answer (score 0):

This is the ObjectAnimator version of your animation. Could you please try this? Hope it helps.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //findViewById(R.id.img_pointer1_id).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bounce));

    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.img_pointer1_id), "translationY", 0, -50, 0);
    animator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(800);
    animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    animator.start();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to change image? Maybe image size or format causes the problem. I tried that code 24x24px png image and cpu usage was %20-25 on different api versions.

Comment: When i run an imageView alone with some trick like Hardware accelerator and animation cache, cpu usage is almost 5% with a spike in loop every time that animation start again to 13% max. But when i add to the screen more static image and a background to my constraintLayout, the problem come up again. All the image that i'm using are passed through a compressor, for lower quality and better performance. Noone image is higher then 166KB. I can share all my image and code if that can help.

Comment: This is the screenshot of Profiler when your code running on API21 device (not emulator). Bouncing pic 113kb png 400x400 px. Maybe it helps. https://imgur.com/a/5whrjL2

Comment: @TizianoSilvi any advance?

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it helped me.

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationY", 180f).start()
```

I read it [there](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/hardware-accel).